# Why does my PHP/Oracle Update query simply refresh the data when I click on Update

Tags: php, oracle

I'm working on a page which allows the user to update the RESULT data field for a specified row within my database on Oracle SQL Developer. I have the code set up in a table structure which allows the user to highlight which specific row of data they would like to edit and save their changes to.

The issue I am now facing in regards to this however is when I click on the "Update" button on the actual page view, the data simply refreshes to it's original condition.

**(E.g I change contents of the field from Pass to Fail > Click Update > Field refreshes with Pass back in that specific field.)**

I'm unsure in this scenario what it is I am exactly doing wrong, because I've defined my UPDATE query and I've references it in the table structure.

**My Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Objective </title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
  $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE OBJECTIVE SET RESULT='{$_POST['Result']}' WHERE OBJECTIVE_ID='{$_POST['hidden']}'";
  oci_parse($conn, $UpdateQuery);
}

?>

<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM OBJECTIVE';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($stid);
?>

<div>
    <table border='1'>
<tr>
    <th>Objective ID</th>
    <th>Objective Type</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Result</th>
    <th>Mission_ID</th>
<tr>

<?php
while($row= oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
?>

<tr>
    <form method = "POST" action="">
    <td><?php echo $row ['OBJECTIVE_ID']?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['OBJECTIVE_TYPE']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['DESCRIPTION']?></td>
    <td><input type ="text" name="Result" value="<?php echo $row['RESULT'];?>"/></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['MISSION_ID']?></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['OBJECTIVE_ID']; ?>" readonly/></td>    
    <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" /></td>
    </form>
<tr>
<?php }?>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am aware of SQL Injections, they are not a concern currently cause the app is only planned to be used on my own server which I myself am the only person whop has access to.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements** with **placeholder values**.

Comment: **Even if it's a private app and you only use it once, do not create code with security leaks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing the update but not executing it...

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
  $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE OBJECTIVE SET RESULT='{$_POST['Result']}' WHERE OBJECTIVE_ID='{$_POST['hidden']}'";
  $stid = oci_parse($conn, $UpdateQuery);
  oci_execute($stid);
}
```

I would look into prepared statements and binds even if using a local machine.

Comment: To reiterate since it is important: without using binds you have a SQL injection security problem.